# pandas calculate the strangeness of the topic

Tags: python, pandas

Here is a very short description of my task. I have a dataframe that looks like this: `df = pd.DataFrame([[2, 0], [2, 1], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [3, 0]], columns=['topic', 'strange'])`

For every topic, I need to caclulate the percentage of rows that are 'strange'. So  the result will be like this `1 - 1/3, 2 - 1/2, 3 - 0`.

The most efficient solution I have come up with is:

```
a = df['topic'].value_counts()
b = df[df['strange'] == 1]['topic'].value_counts()
res = (b / a).fillna(0)
```

---

Also this is most probably reasonably performant and not that ugly, I believe that this can be achieved easier with a smart groupby operation.

Does anyone have other suggestions? Looking for a shorter or faster alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `strange` is guaranteed to be 0 or 1 only, you can just take the mean:

```
In [7]: df.groupby("topic").mean()
Out[7]:
        strange
topic
1      0.333333
2      0.500000
3      0.000000
```

Comment: Actually strange is a boolean value. So it is guaranteed.  This is clearly shorter than mine and also for my 10mln rows dataframe with 200k strange elements your solution takes slightly less time: **3.22 sec** against **2.97**